# the user signature box drifting into the tag info box

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Using Chrome 11

```
Google Chrome   11.0.672.2 (Official Build 75134)
WebKit  534.20 (trunk@78450)
V8  3.1.4
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.672.2 Safari/534.20
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a userscript that is adding the `revisions` and `timeline` links.  This is pushing the signature boxes to the right - there isn't enough room there for the added links, an editor signature, and the owner signature.  Disable the userscript you're using and reload the page to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

That would be issue with my userscript.

I have moved timeline link to another line, so you may install it again here.

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/97069.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/97069)

Answer (score -1):

We do not support beta web browsers. The current released version of Chrome is version 9, and you are *two* versions ahead of that.

[What does "8/7c" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15174/what-does-8-7c-stand-for)

Page looks fine in the current released version of Chrome 9.

Comment: It is whatever userscript that's loaded and adding the links that needs to be blamed, not the non-stable browser.